# japanese character is not supported in localhost

Tags: html

I have a project which has japanese characters in it. When I run the project which is already on the server (the live version) japanese characters are displayed. However, the same files with no changes in the code, if I run on localhost then  japanese characters are displaying something like this "ãƒ¬ã‚¹ãƒˆãƒ©ãƒ³".
all files includes . and i'm using google chrome. 
what should I do to make it support japanese characters?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you using for the Japanese characters? Unicode?

Comment: @Ashish Acharya.. all files in the project includes <meta charset="utf-8">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following:

```
<meta charset="Shift-JIS"/>
```

to your file if you use HTML5, or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Shift-JIS" />
```

if you use HTML 4.01.

The reason why it works over the webserver is because it transmits HTTP headers with correct encoding. On your local copy of `.html`, there are no such headers, so the browser checks the `<meta/>` tags (which are missing), and if it fails to find these, it guesses encoding, which in this case is UTF8. (If you use webserver in localhost too, it might be misconfigured. In any case, it's a good practice to always include charset information.)

@AshishAcharya I'm pretty sure OP uses Shift-JIS rather than UTF8. The page is rendered as UTF8 though.

Comment: do I have to make use of <meta charset="Shift-JIS"/> instead of <meta charset="utf-8"> ??

Comment: Yes. At least if your page is indeed encoded with Shift-JIS. I believe so, otherwise your page wouldn't be rendered wrong. (You might also convert the document itself from Shift-JIS to UTF-8 and leave `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`, which is a better solution, but it's not always feasible.)